# how to create web app back ups in windows azure

Tags: azure, web-applications

I'm beginning to start using Azure and have a published mvc website. I need to deploy a newer version of a website and want to create a back up of the published web app just in case if new deployment breaks I can roll back from the back up. From what I have learned I need to create a storage account to create and retrieve back ups. Not sure what kind of storage this back up will require i.e. a blob, queue,table file etc and also looking for a walk-through how the backups can be done for web apps and retrieved? Any ideas?

Comment: A second slot is the fastest way to roll back a deployment as you just swap slots. How do you deploy to Azure? If you deploy from Source Control you have almost solved your problem already as you have the previous verson

Comment: We are using SVN for managing the source control but deploying using visual studio web deploy. Can you possibly provide link to some sort of a walkthrough how to use the second slot

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/

Answer (score 1):

A second slot is the fastest way to roll back a deployment as you just [swap slots](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/).

> To rollback a production app after swap If any errors are identified
>   in production after a slot swap, roll the slots back to their pre-swap
>   states by swapping the same two slots immediately.

If you deploy from Source Control you have almost solved your problem already as you have the previous version in your repository.

So, a common, simple deployment pattern becomes:

- Deploy to Stage
- Test
- Swap (Stage becomes Live)
- Stop Stage (the old live)
- If there is a problem start Stage and swap back.